# Using AppleScript to create text file with email details via Mail Rule

Tags: email, applescript

I am trying to create an AppleScript to use via a Mail rule to take data from the message, create a text file, and save it to a folder on the desktop. I have tried various iterations that do not give me an error but also don't create the file. I cut the "CREATE DOCUMENT WITH EMAIL INFORMATION" portion into a new AppleScript and set the variables above it as a test and the text file is created, so something isn't moving from my email information variable defining over to my text document creating. I have been teaching myself by reading these forums and am finally stuck, so any help with syntax or errors you see would be appreciated.

```
using terms from application "Mail"
on perform mail action with messages this_message for rule this_rule
    tell application "Mail"

        --CLEAR THE VARIABLES
        set this_messageid to ""
        set this_date to ""
        set this_sender to ""
        set this_subject to ""
        set this_content to ""
        set this_attachments to ""

        -- GET THE MESSAGE ID OF MESSAGE
        set this_messageid to the messageid of this_message

        --GET THE DATE RECEIVED OF MESSAGE
        set this_date to the date received of this_message

        -- GET THE SENDER OF THIS MESSAGE
        set this_sender to the sender of this_message

        -- GET SUBJECT OF MESSAGE
        try
            set this_subject to (subject of this_message) as Unicode text
            if this_subject is "" then error
        on error
            set this_subject to "NO SUBJECT"
        end try

        -- GET CONTENT OF MESSAGE
        try
            set this_content to (every character of content of this_message) as Unicode text
            if this_content is in {"", "?"} then error
        on error error_message
            set this_content to "NO CONTENT"
        end try

        --DETERMINE IF THERE ARE ATTACHMENTS
        if thisMessage's mail attachments is not {} then
            set this_attachments to "Yes"
        end if

        --GET THE MAILBOX ACCOUNT OF MESSAGE
        set this_account to account of mailbox of thisMessage

    end tell



    -- CREATE DOCUMENT WITH EMAIL INFORMATION
    set this_document to open for access ("/Users/username/Desktop/SendToKeepIt/" & "Email " & this_subject & " " & this_messageid & ".txt") with write permission
    write "Airmail Link: " & "airmail://message?mail=" & this_account & "&messageid=" & this_messageid & return & "Mail Link: " & "message://" & "&messageid=" & this_messageid & return & return & "Date: " & this_date & return & "Subject: " & this_subject & return & "Sender: " & this_sender & return & "Attachments?: " & this_attachments & return & return & this_content to this_document
    close access this_document

end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

Update 2018-08-14
Based on the comment below, I made some changes but am still getting the same result, no file is created. Again, if I copy the script portion from "--CREATE..." to "close access" and put variables above the script, I get a file that is exactly what I want, so for some reason the variables I am setting from the mail message are not being used to create the document I assume?

```
using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages these_messages for rule this_rule
        tell application "Mail"
            set the message_count to the count of these_messages
            repeat with i from 1 to the message_count
                set this_message to item i of these_messages

                --CLEAR THE VARIABLES
                (*
                set this_messageid to ""
                set this_date to ""
                set this_sender to ""
                set this_subject to ""
                set this_content to ""
                set this_attachments to "No"
                *)

                -- GET THE MESSAGE ID OF MESSAGE
                set this_messageid to the messageid of this_message

                --GET THE DATE RECEIVED OF MESSAGE
                set this_date to the date received of this_message

                -- GET THE SENDER OF THIS MESSAGE
                set this_sender to the sender of this_message

                -- GET SUBJECT OF MESSAGE
                set this_subject to subject of this_message
                if this_subject is "" then set this_subject to "NO SUBJECT"

                -- GET CONTENT OF MESSAGE
                set this_content to (every character of content of this_message)
                if this_content is in {"", "?"} then set this_content to "NO CONTENT"

                --DETERMINE IF THERE ARE ATTACHMENTS
                if thisMessage's mail attachments is not {} then set this_attachments to "Yes"

                --GET THE MAILBOX ACCOUNT OF MESSAGE
                set this_account to account of mailbox of thisMessage

                -- CREATE DOCUMENT WITH EMAIL INFORMATION
                set this_document to open for access ("/Users/russellread/Desktop/SendToKeepIt/" & "Email " & this_subject & " " & this_messageid & ".txt") with write permission
                write "Airmail Link: " & "airmail://message?mail=" & this_account & "&messageid=" & this_messageid & return & "Mail Link: " & "message://" & "&messageid=" & this_messageid & return & return & "Date: " & this_date & return & "Subject: " & this_subject & return & "Sender: " & this_sender & return & "Attachments?: " & this_attachments & return & return & this_content to this_document
                close access this_document

            end repeat
        end tell
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

Comment: The most glaring oversight is the fact that `this_message` is a list of one or more messages, but you're script treats it as a singular `message` object.  On a lesser note, everywhere you've type-classed something as `Unicode text` can (and probably should) be changed just to  `text`.  Your `try`...`end try` blocks are unnecessary and ill-conceived.  But if you address the main issue, you can then see how close that gets you to your goal.

Comment: I have made some changes to the script which I will repost below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was mostly with mismatched variable names: for example, you defined a variable called `this_message`, but then referred later on in the script to an undefined variable called `thismessage`.

Anyway, here's a revised version of your script:

```
property text item delimiters : linefeed

using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages these_messages for rule this_rule
        tell application "Mail"
            set the message_count to the count of these_messages
            repeat with i from 1 to the message_count
                set this_message to item i of these_messages

                set msg_attr to {this_messageid:message id ¬
                    , this_date:date received ¬
                    , this_sender:sender ¬
                    , this_subject:subject ¬
                    , this_content:content ¬
                    , this_account:name of account of mailbox ¬
                    , has_attachments:mail attachments} of this_message

                if msg_attr's this_subject is "" then ¬
                    set msg_attr's this_subject to "NO SUBJECT"
                ignoring white space
                    if msg_attr's this_content is in {"", "?"} then ¬
                        set msg_attr's this_content to "NO CONTENT"
                end ignoring

                if msg_attr's has_attachments ≠ {} then
                    set msg_attr's has_attachments to "Yes"
                else
                    set msg_attr's has_attachments to "No"
                end if

                -- CREATE DOCUMENT WITH EMAIL INFORMATION
                set fp to "/Users/CK/Desktop/" & "Email " & ¬
                    msg_attr's this_subject & space & ¬
                    msg_attr's this_messageid & ".txt"

                my Write_To_File(fp, msg_attr)
            end repeat
        end tell
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from


to Write_To_File(filepath as text, msg_attr as record)
    local filepath, msg_attr

    set folpath to (POSIX file filepath) & "::" as text as alias

    tell application "System Events" to make new file with properties ¬
        {name:folpath & "tmp-unnamed" as text}

    set this_document to folpath & "tmp-unnamed" as text as alias

    tell msg_attr to set txt to the contents of {¬
        ["Airmail Link: ", "airmail://message?mail=", its this_account, ¬
            "&messageid=", its this_messageid], ¬
        ["Mail Link: ", "message://", "messageid=", its this_messageid], ¬
        [], ["Date: ", its this_date], ¬
        ["Subject: ", its this_subject], ¬
        ["Sender: ", its this_sender], ¬
        ["Attachments?: ", its has_attachments], ¬
        [], its this_content} as text


    write the txt to this_document as «class utf8»

    tell application "System Events" to set name of this_document to filepath
end Write_To_File
```

Comment: Thank you! In case anyone looks at this post for their own issues, the line " set these_messages to selection" results in a message that is selected in the inbox being processed rather than the new message, so I deleted it. Also, to create the Airmail link, the "this_account" variable needs to be set to "email addresses of account of mailbox" to get the actual email address. Once I made those changes it works great! Thank you for the help.